# UISearchBar in UINavigationBar with ScopeBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I am trying to put a UISearchBar inside of the UINavigationBar, which I am able to do without much problem.  The problem is that I have logic when editing to show the Scope Bar.  This all works fine, with one exception.  The navigation bar tries to center the UISearchBar inside of the title view.  This causes the search bar to move up above the navigation bar.  I tried adding some logic to set the frame of the search bar so that it just draws overtop of my main view, which is fine.  I can only set the height, which causes the search bar to draw over the view just fine, but it isn't wide enough to cover the whole screen.  If I set the width on the frame, it goes back to the same behavior of trying to center the UISearchBar on the navigation bar.  Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

hide the navigationBar, and use a UItoolbar instead. you'll see the same type of a bar, but its a lot more flexible in terms of customizing.

Comment: I don't understand how a UIToolBar will help me.  I have a design that I have to mimic, and the design shows a UISearchBar in the navbar with scope buttons.

Comment: is there an existing app in the app store that does this? I may have misunderstood your op

Comment: No, we had a design firm that designed the behavior of the app.  I did come up with a solution though.  I changed my controller to a UIViewController, implemented the tableview delegates, and drew a UIView with my searchbar at the top of the screen.  Then drew the tableview under it.